# How to format only a particular DIV in html? (source-formatting)

Tags: html, dreamweaver, code-formatting

I have a div that contains a single line of unformatted html and I only need to format this div, nothign else in these html pages. I have about 152 pages, with similar formatting and I don't know how I can format these pages...

I used [Simple PHP HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to create these pages and this div didn't get formatted properly.

The format of the is similar to the following:

```
<div class="r_features" itemprop="description">
                                                     <h2>Features</h2>      <ul>        <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li>        <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li>        <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li>        <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li>        <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li>        <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li>        <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li>        <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li> </ul>
                                                    </div>
```

There's an indent on the left to the `r_features` div, and more formatted divs before and after this div. So if I use Dreamweaver to format these pages in batch/bulk, then all the other divs would be disturbed. I only need to keep the existing formatting for the pages, but change this div only.

How could I achieve this without disturbing the other divs? I'm trying to either look for a program or php tool that would let me select the exact div to apply formatting.

Edit :
This is how I need the div to be formatted for the html files... These divs contain lists, tables and paragraphs in a single line as shown in the example above. I'm trying to format these divs similar to the format below:

```
<div class="r_features" itemprop="description">
                                                     <h2>Features</h2>
  <ul>      
    <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li>        
    <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li>        
    <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li>        
    <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li>        
    <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li> 
    <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li>    
    <li>lorem ipsum one two three</li> 
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to format how the html looks as displayed in an editor or how to actually format the div with css?

Comment: How the html looks in the editor.... I'm using notepad++ to edit these files, and this single line of html code in the div is not letting me finish the edits in time... I'm not working on it right now, but will be editing them tomorrow.... thought maybe I could format the source code of these divs today.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ has html tidy plugins that can allow you to tidy up or reformat you html code. Not exaclty sure if that's what you're looking for, but hope it helps.

Comment: I have that plug in installed..! It's got lots of options and I don't know which option would be useful for formatting `specific div only` in batch mode for multiple html files?

Comment: The more I look at this, you're probably more looking for a "replace all" feature ?

Comment: I'm currently browsing via my phone, so don't know what you mean by the replace all feature... I don't need to replace any text... I only need to format the one-line code into multiple-nicely-formatted html code with proper indents/tabs that matches with the entire page's html format. I need to do this for multiple files. Dreamweaver does this easily, but for the whole page... I only need formatting for a specific div, without changing anything else in the page.....

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

I had used `file_get_html()` function in PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser, to get the html content of the file.

During this, the entire html was being converted into a single line string, because the **default argument** for this function, `$stripRN` is set to `true`... due to this, the output to the file was being converted to string, instead of formatted html.

So I first formatted the content in dreamweaver, and then copied that content into the file, by loading the file with the command `file_get_html()` and it's 9th argument set to `false`.

Here's how to use that function for keeping the source formatting unaltered.

```
$html = file_get_html("content_html/$file_name", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, false, NULL, NULL);
```

content_html is a folder in my www directory. $file_name is the html file that's being traversed.